# Как узнать когда зашел на сервер в дискорде?

Tags: javascript, discord

Я понял как можно узнать дату регистрации, но как узнать дату захода на сервер - нет.

Код:
`` const joinedserver = (`mentioneduser.joinedAt.getDate() + 1) ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если умеете выбирать юзеров, то вот:
`const joinedserver = guildmember.joinedAt.getDate();`

Советую попользоваться сайтом **https://discord.js.org/#/**.
Вот по этой теме страничка: **https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=joinedAt**